# how can i do delaunay triangulation of simple polygon and find it's neighbors for any triangles in cgal

Tags: c++, triangulation, cgal, delaunay

how can i do using CGAl, Delaunay triangulation of polygon (simple without hole and in cw   order)   and get a list of the neighbors of triangles for any triangle that generated from the Delaunay triangulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the example in the User Manual:
http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/index.html#title29

You must distinguish between faces in and outside of the polygon.

When you have a face handle you can get the three neighbor faces
with the function neighbor(i)   for i = 0, 1, and 2

See: 
http://doc.cgal.org/latest/TDS_2/classTriangulationDSFaceBase__2.html

Answer (score 0):

You can download my PHP class delaunay triangulation @ phpclasses.org. To find all adjacent triangle you can download my class voronoi @ phpclasses.org. To pull adjacent triangle of my class you need to loop through each vertex.